# Application specific suitable JVM GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am trying to run a java program in eclipse giving different parameters as VM arguments. Like.

```
-XX:+UseParallelGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweep.
```

I am printing log file too. My intention is to understand which GC is suitable for my program. How can I decide it?

Comment: There are lots of factors involved in deciding the choice of GC. Some of them are: Nature of application. Life and amount of object creation. End user experience requirement. The answer of this question is out of scope without much details known

Comment: "Experimentation," or well-planned testing.  You should develop a test plan to determine which is the best GC.  Trying the app under load with two or more GC configuration would be a start.  Analyze the results and then extrapolate to determine the direction for future tests.

Comment: @markspace, I tried to upload my log file into www.gceasy.io . But it prompts GC log format is not recognized. Could you please help me out to generate proper GC log format?

Comment: Zobs - the FAQ says: "Q: GCEasy isn't able to parse my GC Logs? What should I do?  A: Please report it to team@tier1app.com. We will fix it."

Comment: Unless you have a problem, the one you have is probably suitable.  I would wait until you have a realist work load to test.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define what constitutes "suitable"
2. run different sets of parameters under realistic workloads
3. measure each run
4. determine whether criteria defined in 1. are met

GC logs may help with 3 but depending on your definitions in 1 you may want to log application-specific metrics.